# What does app not installed mean?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab

When I try to install an update on angrybirds epic rpg,it says "app not installed" what does that mean?It takes up 105.9 mb I have 500 mb left on my device.I have an android tablet.

Comment: I think you should edit and reflect the actual issue and the steps you took to trace the issue. "App not installed" means the app did not install. It's quite plain to understand. What you should be asking (IMO) is how do I know why the app did not install?

Comment: If I get you correcty then your tablet has the app already installed and all you want to do is to install an update from the Playstore. So why is your Tablet not recognizing the app as installed? Please go to settings - apps - angry birds epic and see if you can "move it to the tablet". I think it has downloaded the assets to the sd-card and somehow doesn't recognize it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It can mean many reasons, maybe out of memory, incompatible app, problems to your ROM, conflicting currently installed apps and etc.

Maybe you can try booting your phone to safe mode to remove conflicting apps . You can also try rebooting your phone.

Hope this may help!

Comment: That helped a lot thnx guys